# Scikit learn - initialize DictVectorizer with numpy.float32

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to use DictVectorize from Scikit-learn, but initialize it with numpy.float32 instead of the default numpy.float64. I tried to do it like this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer(dtype=<type 'np.float32'>,sparse=False)
```

but this is not working. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not valid Python syntax. It's

```
import numpy as np
DictVectorizer(dtype=np.float32, sparse=False)
```